# FPV camera and beeper seems to be interfering with each other

Tags: flight-controller, video-transmitters, receiver, electronics, fpv-cameras

I recently changed my VTX from the Tbs unify pro 5G8 HV to the unify pro 5G8 V3. Because of this I had to move the cameras 5v input from the VTX to the FC (The HV model has a built in regulator, and the V3 doesn't). I also mounted the VTX on a 5v output on the FC instead of vbat.

Now to the problem: When I turn on the drone everything is fine until the beeper beeps once. This causes the cameras image to go gray momentarily.

When I then turn on the transmitter and start the beeper shortly, it never turns off, it just starts beeping with shorter and faster beeps. This also causes the camera feed to go gray.

My hypothesis is that the 5v regulator becomes overloaded since all peripherals are connected to 5v. Could this be correct?

I should also mention that the OSD is visible at all times, so the problem is definitely with the camera and not the VTX. The FC is a HobbyWing Xrotor fc f4 g2.

Update: I desoldered the beeper, and the camera image still becomes partially gray, but only when I turn on the transmitter.

Comment: Curious! You say this partial-graying/dimming is momentary during startup when you first turn the drone on?

Comment: Yes, there is a kind of startup beep from the beeper that I assume causes the dimming

Comment: But you also said that the dimming doesn't go away when you've removed the buzzer, right?

Comment: Yes, not completely. But it is definitely worse when the buzzer is there

Comment: Could just be a rocky/failing 5V regulator on your FC. That would explain the power interruptions during startup if true, ut I have no way of making a formal diagnosis.

Comment: I have ordered an external 5v regulator. I'll let you know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed the 5V regulator. I bought an external 5V 1.2A regulator and hooked up the camera and VTX to it, and all my problems have disappeared.